# Emacs 24 in Ubuntu 14.04: Can I remove whitespace of the toolbar?

Tags: emacs

I have installed Emacs 24 in Ubuntu 14.04 using `sudo apt-get install emacs`.
However it has strange white space in the leftside of the toolbar.

[image: Notice the leftside of the toolbar]

**Can I remove that, or at least change the color of it?**

I have tried the following but none worked:

- Turning off the "fringe" option, but it is separate from toolbar whitespace.
- I already know how to remove the entire toolbar `(tool-bar-mode -1)` but I like the toolbar so I don't want to do that.
- I have googled "emacs toolbar" or some other keywords but I cannot find meaningful answers.
- I have tried editing .Xresources but I don't know what the toolbar related settings are named. Google didn't reveal much other than hiding the entire toolbar (`emacs.toolBar: off`).

Answer (score 1):

The default Ubuntu themes (*Ambiance* and *Radiance*) do not contain the handlebox graphics, so the "handlebox" in Emacs appear as a whitespace. The Ubuntu theme team did not design the handlebox graphics because **the handlebox widgit is deprecated in GTK3 (the toolkit Emacs 24 uses).** This is reported in the [Emacs upstream mailing-list](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/GtkHandleBox-in-GTK3-looks-awful-and-is-deprecated-can-we-stop-using-it-td309895.html) and a developer has comfirmed this problem. I don't know if/when this problem will be addressed in future versions of Emacs however.

**Workaround:**
The *Clearlooks-Phenix* theme available in the repository has proper graphics for the "handlebox" of the toolbar. You can install it by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install clearlooks-phenix-theme
```

*oxygen-gtk* theme also has proper graphics for handlebox, but it has graphical glitches when you hover your mouse cursor on the toolbar buttons.

I would appreciate you if you know how to add handlebox graphics to Ambiance and Radiance themes, or how to remove the Emacs's handlebox. But for now I can live with Clearlooks-Phenix theme.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.emacs`

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(fringe-mode 0 nil (fringe))
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but "fringe" is a separate entity from the toolbar handlebox.

Comment: I see, you just want to remove the upper space before the toolbar. Not easy.